# Thrust to weight

Tags: power, fan

Want to put a ducted fan or shrouded propeller motor on a snowboard. How much thrust would be needed to propel 275 on a snowboard? I'm aiming for a speed between 15-25 mph. The board would be 169 cm long and 30 cm wide, freshly waxed. Snow would be packed with 2"-5" of fresh powder. Is this feasible?

Comment: should read 275 lbs

Comment: This is clearly an engineering question. To get you started, estimate the slope angle that it would take to get up to the desired velocity. This will give you the needed propelling force. There is still an open parameter here, which is the fan diameter. The larger you make the fan, the less power it will take.

Comment: If you're planning on going down a snow covered skiing trail with this thing, attaining a speed of 15-25 mph will be no problem. Your problem will be how to slow down and steer the thing so you don't run into a tree at 100 mph. Sounds like a death wish to me.

Comment: I'm not saying anything further out of liability concerns and advice from my lawyer.  :-)

Comment: @SamuelWeir: There is nothing to be afraid of here... go to youtube and search for paramotor skiing... these guys are fearless... they are even taking the protective meshes off the motors. Who doesn't want their arms shredded to pieces in an accident? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne - Thanks, haven't heard of that one but I have seen some of the crazy things that people are doing with gliding "wingsuits". Absolutely insane. A 100 mph out-of-control ducted fan snowboard going down a  ski slope might be right up there with them. I'm looking forward to seeing it on YouTube.

Comment: @SamuelWeir: Personally I am not giving in to any of these trivialities. I am saving my money for my "personal rocket chair orbital access vehicle" (PERCOAV) to get me to my future job on the ISS every morning on time. Light me up!